# Azure Function V2 HttpClient POST to WebAPI on .NET Framework 4.5 results in NULL payload

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which is uses V2-beta runtime and POSTs to a WebAPI endpoint, the payload is always NULL.

If I use V1 of Azure function then the payload comes in fine.

**Azure function runtime**: V2-beta
**WebAPI service**: .NET Framework 4.5, AspNet WebAPi 2
**Endpoint uses**: Strongly typed model
**Result**: NULL

---

**Azure function runtime**: V2-beta
**WebAPI service**: .NET Framework 4.5, AspNet WebAPi 2
**Endpoint uses**: HttpRequestMessage
**Result**: Object is populated

---

**Azure function runtime**: V1
**WebAPI service**: .NET Framework 4.5, AspNet WebAPi 2
**Endpoint uses**: Strongly typed model
**Result**: Properties populated

---

```
new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync(payload).Result;
```

Is this something is which is a known behavior?

Please can someone enlighten me what could be causing this behavior?

Thanks